# What are the additonal arguments for the TInyMCE's Editor.insertContent?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Per the [documentation](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.insertContent),

```
public function insertContent(content:String, args:Object):void
```

> args -- Optional args to pass to insert call.

This is not very descriptive. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place? What are these magical optional args and what can be accomplished with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/classes/InsertContent.js) only `paste` and `merge` (both boolean) are allowed in the args object.

Both appear to be internal markup clean-up tools (only used by the core plugin [Paste](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/classes/SmartPaste.js)) and don't seem to be overly useful for 3rd party developers.

In summary: The args can be ignored.